# Display internet interface and IP adresses in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to display internet interface names and associated ip adresses of my computer.

This is the code I have :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct ifaddrs * addr;

    getifaddrs(&addr);

    while (addr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", addr->ifa_name);
        char ipv6addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        char ipv4addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

        switch (addr->ifa_addr->sa_family)
        {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr->ifa_addr;
                printf(" -> %s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), ipv4addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN));
                break;
            }
            case AF_INET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) addr->ifa_addr;
                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), ipv6addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                printf(" -> %s\n", ipv6addr);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        addr = addr->ifa_next;
    }

    printf("--------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I get a very strange display, though :

```
lo0
lo0
 -> 127.0.0.1
lo0
 -> ::1
lo0
 -> fe80::1
gif0
stf0
en6
en6
 -> fe80::aede:4fff:fe00:1120
en0
en0
 -> fe80::10e8:5a0c:a5ea:a000
en0
 -> 158.31.24.216
en2
en4
en3
en1
bridge0
p2p0
awdl0
awdl0
 -> fb80::82b:ccff:fe11:4180
llw0
llw0
 -> fe80::82b:ccbb:fe12:4180
utun0
utun0
 -> fe82::f3cc:a285:31fd:8d55
utun1
utun1
 -> fe80::25e0:ce34:c043:374c
utun2
utun2
 -> fe80::25e0:ce34:c043:374c
utun3
utun3
 -> fe80::25e0:ce34:c043:374c
utun4
utun4
 -> fe80::25e0:ce34:c043:374c
--------------
```

The display i'm looking for is something like :

interface name -> ip adress.

but the loop seems to act weirdly as well as the switch..

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: *"but the loop seems to act weirdly as well as the switch"* - What is "weirdly"? Looks like the switch is simply hitting the default case in some cases (Read: `sa_family` is neither `AF_INET` nor `AF_INET6`), loop looks like it's acting perfectly normal, and the reason you're not getting something like "interface name -> ip adress." is because you output your interface names and IP addresses on different lines.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look through the man page for `getifaddrs`, specifically the description of `ifa_addr` and the example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html

Comment: Hmm, code is having trouble yet does not check the return values of functions like `inet_ntop()`, `getifaddrs()` for errors.  Seems like that is a better first step than stack-overflow - even though OP's issue is likely a format one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the first print for interface name at the beginning of while loop

```
printf("%s\n", addr->ifa_name); //Remove this line
```

And in each case statement put the `addr->ifa_name` so as to print the interface name once for each IPv4 and IPv6 as shown below:

```
switch (addr->ifa_addr->sa_family)
{
    case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr->ifa_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), ipv4addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("%s -> %s\n", addr->ifa_name, ipv4addr);
            break;
        }

    case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) addr->ifa_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), ipv6addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("%s -> %s\n", addr->ifa_name, ipv6addr);
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
}
```

**Output:**

```
lo -> 127.0.0.1
enp0s3 -> 10.1.10.231
docker0 -> 172.17.0.1
lo -> ::1
enp0s3 -> fe80::c664:be15:255e:b581
docker0 -> fe80::42:1dff:fedd:d5b7
--------------
```